# Use Javascript Object in PHP without POST or AJAX

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to pass a JSON object directly into PHP and work with it?

Something like this:

```
<script>
 var gridData = {"id":100,"level":"B","Zone":"Entry"}; 
</script>
<?php
echo "Your grid Information is:". [**How to get the gridData displayed here**]
?>
```

I know I can pass to backend using AJAX, get the result and show it up in a div, but is there an easier way since I am already in this page and I already have the data in Javascript?

Also please note: I am working off some really old legacy code I inherited with lot of business logic calculations in a custom javascript platform, so please bear with me that the whole architecture is a bit odd :)

Comment: How about a **GET**? :) You have to send a request to get anything from the HTML into a server. How would you expect for something to get from your browser to the server without an HTTP request?

Comment: Aaah..I see, I got completely confused. Basically if PHP does need to work with my data, it needs to make it to the server. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.

Javascript is executed *on the client* **after** php has completely finished its execution *on the server*.

Comment: Guess the only way is to send it back to the server..thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you turn this on your head and define your JSON in PHP, and then emit the Javascript?  So you could have something like this:

```
<?php
    $json = '{"id":100,"level":"B","Zone":"Entry"}';
?>
<script>
    var gridData = <?php echo $json ?>;
</script>
<?php
    echo "Your grid Information is:". $json
?>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but from his question it sounds like the gridData json is being generated dynamically on the client-side by some sort of user interaction. So it's never on the server to begin with. This won't work.

Comment: Doesn't deserve a down vote, this answer is trying to make sense of a question that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree with Juan Mendes, doesn't deserve a down-vote (I tried to +1the effort Ethan took to try to help, but I don't have enough reputation apparently), though I do not know how my question doesn't make sense..

Comment: Thanks, Juan & open_source...I thought the downvote was a bit harsh myself.  Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** way to use Javascript in conjunction with PHP.

You are dealing with two completely different types of languages here: **client-side** and **server-side**.

**Server-side** languages (like PHP) execute on the web server. They are used to dynamically generate the page that is being displayed. Everything they do executes on the web server. Once the PHP script is finished running and the page is generated, it gets sent to the user's web browser.

**Client-side** languages (like Javascript) execute completely on the local machine in your browser. They are ignorant of what goes on on the server. All they know how to do is manipulate the DOM elements of a static web page once it has been sent to the browser.

Comment: Just to be accurate: JavaScript is primarily used on the client but it's also used on the server, http://nodejs.org/, so the real difference is just that code is running on two different computers. To exchange data, no matter what the language, you're going to have to go through the network